# Subtract 1 from current date/counting from yesterdays date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to include data 30 days back starting from yesterday. I've tried several ways but the syntax is not agreeing with me. I'm using BigQuery.

```
WHERE DATE(created_at) > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: what type of `created_at`? what error you are getting?

Comment: created_at is a field in my table. The above code works but it counts from today. I don't know how to make it start from yesterday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The above code works but it counts from today. I don't know how to make it start from yesterday

Use below

```
WHERE DATE(created_at) BETWEEN 
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) 
  AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend:

```
WHERE created_at > TIMETAMP(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
```

This assumes that `created_at` is a `timestamp`.